# JS \ PHP уменьшение значения каждые Х минут и запись в БД

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть 3 php переменные

```
$sum = '1000',  - начальное число 
$time = '60000', - время в мс
$minussum = '100' - вычитаемое число
```

также  есть 2 кнопки "Старт" и "Стоп".
Нужно по клику на кнопку запускать отсчет так чтобы от $sum каждые 60 секунд отнималось $minussum, а результат записывался в БД. В случае если $sum = 0 или меньше $minussum нужно останавливать отсчет.

Вопрос собственно в том как записывать данные в БД каждые $time секунд и по окончанию остановить процесс.

Comment: Это на сервере должно выполняться или можно на стороне клиента? Если на стороне клиента, то просто отправляйте ajax на сервер каждые 60 сек по клину на кнопку. Если на php на сервере, то без костылей не обойтись ибо не для этого он задумывался

Comment: Здравствуйте. Все происходит на стороне клиента и отправка запросов с помощью SetInterval уже работает. Спасибо, направили меня в верную сторону, я все пытался слишком усложнить.

Comment: На клиенте отправлять запрос на сервер для уменьшения значения - не очень хорошая идея. Потому что запрос может не дойти. Javascript можно отключить. В итоге ваше значение не будет уменьшаться.Лучше сохранить в базе время начала и время конца. И высчитывать временной промежуток каждый раз, можно узнать на сколько уменьшилось значение. Например: `$remain = sum -trunc(($endTime-$startTime)/60)*$minussum`

Comment: Спасибо, рассмотрю как вариант.